# How to drive an armature from a gear/horn animated on the timeline

Tags: animation, armature, timeline

I have an Armature with an Inverse Kinematic that I wish to 'push' radially from from a gear horn. I have both the gear animated on a timeline and the armature built. I don't understand how to get the gear horn to drive the armature.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUAWG4iX7L0

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about animation but I think you can add a bone constrain to the IK controller bone that copies the location of the peg on the green arm.
[image]
This moves that bone and the IK system when you move the cube in object mode so I assume it'd work with the animation
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a try.